# Kate editor - Code Folding

Tags: kate

Is it possible to fold the python code in Kate editor?

Since Python does not have any braces, I think the editor is not able to fold the code.

Without folding it becomes difficult to manage the long code.
Can we mark the regions in the code to fold?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think these is a complete solution, but a nice workaround. Languages like Python and R don't have braces, so most editors fail to fold them. So you can just comment a brace like:

```
if (1 = 1): # {
...
...
# }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to fold Python code in Kate?

Yes. You can click any `▼` or `►` symbols along the left-hand border (where the line numbers appear) to fold or unfold code.

*ex. Unfolded Python Code (`▼`)*

[image: Unfolded Python Code - Kate Editor - Screenshot]

*ex. Folded Python Code (`►`)*

[image: Folded Python Code - Kate Editor - Screenshot]

> Since Python doesn't have any braces, I think Kate isn't able to fold the code.

Braces are not required for code folding in Kate.

In Python, indentation serves the same purpose as braces (i.e. separating out blocks of related code for parsing). Kate is aware of this and can place icons automatically to allow folding and unfolding of code blocks it believes to be related.

If you aren't seeing any `▼` or `►` symbols at all, you may wish to double-check that the markers for code folding are visible under *View → Code Folding → Show Folding Markers*:

*ex. Folding Marker Visibility*

[image: Folding Marker Visibility - Kate Editor - Screenshot]

---

*Note that all of the above assumes Kate knows that you are working on a Python file (ex. the file has a `.py` extension).*

---

**Caveat**

With that said, however, it seems as if the rules Kate uses to determine if a block of Python code is foldable do not always appear to provide `▼` symbols for (arguably) related blocks of code.

As a thought, if you just want better marking for code folding in Python, you may simply want to try another editor. Two that have excellent marking for code folding with Python are [Geany](https://www.geany.org/) and [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/).

The drawbacks here are that Geany might be somewhat feature limited depending on what you may want (though it does have [plugins](https://plugins.geany.org/)) and Notepad++ is technically Windows-only (though at least older versions could run under [Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2983) to a degree).

> Can we mark the regions in the code to fold?

I am not aware of any way to do this.

This [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/bokov/71392f18e3b6aadac06edf037c003504) seems to imply that, at least in the past, it was possible to edit or add files to Kate to allow this. However, reading around about the new framework Kate is currently built under (version 5), it seems like the primary file for working with Python was potentially folded into something that isn't really editable unless you're perhaps building it yourself (but this is just my impression - I could be wrong).